# How to make a branch from branch that is under /tags Repo Directory in teamcity

Tags: svn, tags, branch, teamcity

MyRoot URL is http://Repositories/svn/ibtis/ and checkout rule is +:tags\TestReleaseHead=>.

Now I have set the labelling rule as /tags/TestReleaseHead=>/tags. But it seems its not doing anything. Any Idea How can I branch something under the tags directory to someother version.
My Repository structure is like this

```
http://Repositories/svn/ibtis/
-branches
-tags
-trunk
-test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the second step of your build configuration, the "Version Control Settings" have you set up vcs labelling ?

Looks like you only set up the labelling rules for now.

see image bellow.

[image]